# Neural network generating incorrect results that are around the average of outputs

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I'm working on a neural network system to perform [SED fitting](http://www.sedfitting.org/SED08/Welcome.html) as part of a studentship project at the University of Western Australia.

I have created a set of around 20,000 runs through an SED fitting program known as [MAGPHYS](http://www.iap.fr/magphys/magphys/MAGPHYS_files/readme.pdf). Each run has the 42 input values and 32 output values that we're interested in (there are more outputs from the system, but we don't need them)

I've been experimenting around with the Keras neural network package in order to create a network to learn this function.

My current network design uses 4 hidden layers, fully interconnected, with 30 connections between each layer. Each layer is using TanH activation functions. I also have a 42 dimension input layer and 32 dimension output layer, both also using TanH activation, for a total of 6 layers.

```
model = Sequential()
loss = 'mse'
optimiser = SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.0, decay=0, nesterov=True)

model.add(Dense(output_dim=30, input_dim=42, init='glorot_uniform', activation='tanh'))

for i in range(0, 4):
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=30, input_dim=30, init='glorot_uniform', activation='tanh'))

model.add(Dense(output_dim=32, input_dim=30, init='glorot_uniform', activation='tanh'))
model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimiser)
```

I have been using min/max normalisation of my input and output data to squash all of the values between 0 and 1. I'm using a stochastic gradient descent optimiser and I've experimented with various loss functions such as mean squared error, mean absolute error, mean absolute percentage error etc.

**The main issue is that regardless of how I structure my network, it simply generates output values that are around the average of all of the training output values.** It does not appear as through the network has actually learned the function correctly, it just generates values around the average. Worse still, some network designs I've experimented with, particularly those that use linear activation functions, will generate ONLY the average of the output values and will not vary at all.

Example (for one of the 32 outputs):

```
Output   Correct
9.42609868658  =   9.647
9.26345946681  =   9.487
9.43403506231  =   9.522
9.35685760748  =   9.792
9.20564885211  =   9.287
9.39240577382  =   8.002
```

Notice how all of the outputs are just around the 9.2 - 9.4 value, even though these values are quite incorrect.

**With all of this in mind, what causes a network such as mine to generate these sorts of outputs that are all around the average?**

**What sort of things can I try to remedy this problem and create a network, of some sort, to actually generate correct outputs?**

Comment: The common reason for this behavior is that features are not meaningful. They basically do not explain your data. This is actually not that uncommon. However, in most cases If observed that were mainly due to preprocessing errors. Have you tried sth. simpler, e.g., build a linear model (if it works you use neural network library wrongly), not normalize the data to avoid such effects. Furthermore, you can try to include the output in the input.

Comment: Looks like it is stuck in local minimum. I had this problem when I applied my BP NN to a set of data that I used an arbitrary coding for.  Have a look at this - it may help point you in the right direction... http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/pseries/CCN09/CCN-wk8-1.pdf (there's a section on Stuck in a Local Minimum)

Comment: @CAFEBABE So somehow the network can't find any meaningful connection between the inputs and outputs? To my knowledge there has to be one as these same inputs can be run through the MAGPHYS program to produce valid outputs.

Comment: @S.Foster: Sure. The simplest thing would be an error in your pre-processing. I have had such problems, typically very small ones to often myself.
A second, which comes to my mind, is that there might be dependencies between the rows (training examples), e.g., sth like t |-> f(t-1)+t. This would require some recurrent structure. However, I dont understand the SED domain well enough. 
However, The local mininima explanation sounds actually very reasonable to  me as well.

Comment: @CAFEBABE Could you post your comments as an answer?

Answer (score 6):

I just want to throw out some thoughts on this specific problem, in addition to CAFEBABE's comment:

1. 42 input features is not a ton of features to work with. Not something you can necessarily fix, but it means that you'll want to have wider hidden layers (ie more nodes), to help with separability of the classes/labels. Furthermore, 20K observations isn't exactly a large dataset. If you can get more data, you should. This is pretty much always the case.
2. If you have a concrete reason for min/max normalization, then disregard this point, but you could consider BatchNormalizing your input, which tends to help the network's ability to predict accurately. This essentially allows the activation to have inputs occurring closer to the middle of the function, rather than the ends.
3. You should experiment more with your optimization. For example:

   - How many epochs are you running the training for? One pass over the data isn't enough.
   - Try different optimizers, like `rmsprop` or `adam`, or learning rates.
   - You could also use a learning rate scheduler, like [here](http://keras.io/callbacks/#learningratescheduler), where you decrease your learning rate over the epochs, so that you don't shoot past minima of your loss function.
4. Try some different activation functions. Recent research includes: ReLU, ELU, PReLU, SReLU. All available in keras.
5. Also try including some regularization, to avoid overfitting. Look into Dropout, or L2/L1
6. While having a deeper model (ie more layers) does often help, reducing the data dimensions from 42 features, down to 30, is likely hurting your ability to separate the data. Try something bigger, like 100, or 500, or 1000.

An example model you could try would be something like:

```
# imports 
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import ELU     

# data shapes
n_obs, n_feat = 20000, 42
n_hidden = 500 # play with this, bigger tends to give better separability
n_class = 32

# instantiate model
model = Sequential()

# first layer --- input
model.add(Dense(input_dim = n_feat, output_dim = n_hidden))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(ELU())
model.add(Dropout(p=0.2)) # means that 20% of the nodes are turned off, randomly

# second layer --- hidden
model.add(Dense(input_dim = n_hidden, output_dim = n_hidden))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(ELU())
model.add(Dropout(p=0.2))

# third layer --- output
model.add(Dense(input_dim = n_hidden, output_dim = n_class))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

# configure optimization
model.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# split your data, so you test it on validation data
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(data, targets)

# train your model
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data = (X_test, Y_test))
```

Best of luck!